# AWK - OR within an AND statment

Tags: awk

How do I get AWK to print every line that has column 10 being greater than 0.9 as long as the 11th column is not equal to 1 or -1??
I have tried variations on this but it is not working. Thanks!

```
awk '{ if ($10>0.9 && ( $11!=1 || $11!=-1 ) ) print }' file.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please add samples of input and output too in your post in CODE TAGS?

Comment: You are getting OR and AND mixed up. You want *"Column 11 is not equal to -1 AND not equal to 1"*. You can do: `awk '$10>.0.9 && $11!=1 && $11!=-1' file.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have output where 10th field is greater than `0.9` and 11th column is either NOT equal to `1` or `-1` then do following.

```
awk '($10>0.9) && ($11 != 1 || $11 != -1)'  Input_file
```

In case you want to have output where 10th field is greater than `0.9` and 11th column is NOT equal to both `1` and `-1`.

```
awk '($10>0.9 && $11 != 1 && $11 != -1)'  Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** As per ED sir's solution adding following too here.

```
awk '($10 > 0.9) && ($11^2 != 1)' Input_file
```

Comment: `$11 != 1 || $11 != -1` is always true. Since the field cannot be equal to 1 and -1 at the same time, one of terms is always satisfied